What are natural units?
I need to make a presentation on natural units. My professor asked me to visualize a world where $c$ and $\hbar$ are actually equal to unity. Like, what are the consequences? I also want to know the philosophical meaning behind natural units.

Hi! Check out wikipedia first :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units. Having these two equal 1, you then should check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units.

Sydney Coleman described a spinning basketball as having a tiny speed but an enormous angular momentum, in natural units.

The philosophical meaning of natural units is that units are a human choice and thus have no physical significance.

Maybe your professor means a world where, for exampe, $c$ and $\hbar$ have values such that their effects can be seen and experienced by humans? SI units are based around units that are natural to humans: 1 meter, 1 second, 1 kilogram etc. So to make these effects measurable, you would to have to put them to 1 in SI units. For example $c=1m/s$ or $\hbar=j\cdot s$. Natural units are quite different from this. They are just one kind of measuring system and they don't modify the actual values of physical constants. Like metric or imperial units.

As a sidenote, for more philosophical insights, I recommend to browse the tag [tag:natural-units] and similar on this site. You might also find this question helpful.

@AccidentalTaylorExpansion yes .....a world where c and h are actually equal to 1 m/s and 1 Js... that's what I'm asking

You already live in a world where natural units apply. The speed of light is exactly $1$ light-year/year, or equivalently $1$ light-second/second.
Or approximately $1$ foot/nanosecond. This is useful for designing computer circuits. It helps you figure out how far a signal can propagate in one clock cycle.
You can choose units where $\hbar$ is also exactly $1$.
This allows you to simplify equations. For example, $E=m$. Or for a beam of light, $d = t$.
This helps clarify some concepts. In space-time, space and time are on equal footing. $d = t$ makes this clearer than $d = ct$.
We live in a world dominated by gravity. Horizontal distance is an entirely different thing than altitude. They are unrelated concepts. They have different names and units. We use kilometers for horizontal distances, $x$, and meters for altitude, $h$.
If you want to calculate a slope, s, you need a special constant, $K$, that I just made up. $K = 0.001$ km/m. $K$ is a fundamental property of the universe.
$$s = Kh/x$$
But if you use natural units and measure everything in meters, equations get simpler. You start to see relationships that were obscured.

But you cannot make everything be unity, because look at the fine structure constant, which always evaluates to about 1/137 no matter what unit system you use.

Is second really a natural unit? In contrast to a year I know nothing in nature which would lasts exactly one second.

I meant that units exist where c and $\hbar$ are exactly one. I didn't mean to imply that those units had to be based on seconds or years.
